# Присвоить высоту дочернего элемента к родителю jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Помогите решить проблему. Мне нужно присвоить высоту контейнера внутри активного дочернего элемента родителю при помощи jQuery. Дочерние элементы выполнены на абсолютах (к сожалению без этого не обойтись, так как используется плагин для горизонтальной прокрутки).
Вот моя разметка:

```html
<div id="pagepiling" data-id="fullpage">
    <section class="main__offer section" data-anchor="Page-1">
        <div class="container">

        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="about section" id="Page-2" data-anchor="Page-2">
        <div class="container">

        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="help section pp-scrollable" id="Page-3" data-anchor="Page-3" data-id="section"> 
        <div class="container">

        </div>
    </section>
```

Нужно присваивать div id="pagepiling" значение высоты контейнера секции у которой сейчас есть класс active.
Пробовал сделать следующим образом:

```js
$('#pagepiling').height(function(){
     if ( $('.section').hasClass('active').length != 0){
      return $('.section').children('.container').outerHeight(true);
     }
   });
```

Но в таком случае он присваивает высоту только контейнера первой секции, а при последующем переключении значение не меняет.
Своих знаний не хватает(
Буду премного благодарен

Comment: Сейчас Вы присваеваете родительскому блоку высоту единоразово, в момент загрузки страницы. Вам необходимо каждый раз при смене активного блока заново перечитывать высоту и присваевать ее родителю.

Comment: а класс active в каком случае присваивается?

Comment: Active присваивается секции которая видимая сейчас про перелистывании секций.

Comment: Я примерно так и понял, не могли бы вы практически показать как организовать при смене блока перечитывание параметров?

Answer (score 0):

В общем то вопрос решил.

```
function sectHeight () {
  $('#pagepiling').height(function(){
     if ( $('.section').hasClass('active')){
        return $('.section.active').children('.container').outerHeight(true);
     }
  });
};
```

А затем вывел эту функцию в функции добавления класса active к секции